# form_for with validation does not called "create" action correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I had a form that I want user to answer every question, so I add a model-level validation.
I supposed if it pass validation, it should redirect to another page call "scenario" (I haven't finish it's view so it should show template missing). If it does not pass validation, it should render once again to the new page, remains the information already filled in, and show validation error.

But no matter I filled out those fields or not, when I click submit button, it always show me the index page instead of "new" or "scenario"(which should be template missing). It seems ignore what I have wrote in the action "create", and "create" is never been called.

I use rails c and insert a new record to test validation. It does work well, so I guess there is no problem for my model and validation.

I also try to make form_for redirect to "scenario" directly, to make sure it work well for form_for, and it does show templete missing to me, so there might be some problem for "create" itself. I really don't know what's going wrong.

`<%= form_for @subject, :url => { :controller => 'appstores', :action => 'scenario' } do |f| %>`

There is a similar question: [rails form_for never invokes the create controller action to use redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956346/rails-form-for-never-invokes-the-create-controller-action-to-use-redirect-to).
I had try to use "respond_with", not work. And also check my controller is named as appstroes_controller.rb with resources :appstores in routes.rb.

I use rails 4.2.4, ruby 2.0.0, and bootstrap 3, don't know whether the version cause those problem or not.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

> app/controller/appstores_controller.rb

```
class AppstoresController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @subject = Subjectinfo.new
    end

    def create
        @subject = Subjectinfo.new(params[:subjectinfo])
        if @subject.save
            redirect_to :action => "scenario"
        else # if not pass DB validation
          render :action => :new
        end
    end

    def scenario
    end
end
```

> app/view/appstores/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @subject, :url => { :controller => 'appstores', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>    
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :username, "User Name：", :class=>"control-label", :for=>"username" %>
        <% if @subject.errors[:username].presence %>
            <span class="model-error"><%= @subject.errors[:username].join(", ") %></span>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, :autocomplete=>"off", :placeholder=>"User Name", :class=>"form-control", :id=>"username" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :mobile_user, "Are you a mobile device user?", :class=>"control-label", :for=>"mobile_user" %>
        <% if @subject.errors[:mobile_user].presence %>
            <span class="model-error"><%= @subject.errors[:mobile_user].join(", ") %></span>
        <% end %>
        <div class="radio radio-primary">
            <%= f.radio_button :mobile_user, "1", :id=>"mobile_user_1" %>
            <%= f.label :mobile_user, "Yes", :class=>"control-label", :for=>"mobile_user_1" %>
        </div>
        <div class="radio radio-primary">
            <%= f.radio_button :mobile_user, "0", :id=>"mobile_user_0" %>
            <%= f.label :mobile_user, "No", :class=>"control-label", :for=>"mobile_user_0" %>
        </div>
  </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <%= f.submit "NEXT", :class => "btn btn-default btn-outline btn-lg" %>
        </div>
</form>
<% end %>
```

> app/modle/subjectinfo.rb
>
> (to support "attr_accessible" for rails 4, I had put "gem 'protected_attributes'" in my Gemfile)

```
    class Subjectinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates_presence_of :username, :mobile_user
        attr_accessible :username, :mobile_user
    end
```

> config/routes.rb

```
AppStore::Application.routes.draw do
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :via => :all
    root :to => "appstores#index"
    resources :appstores
    get "appstores/scenario"=>"appstores#scenario"
end
```

> rake routes

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
                            /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
                root GET    /                                      appstores#index
           appstores GET    /appstores(.:format)                   appstores#index
                     POST   /appstores(.:format)                   appstores#create
        new_appstore GET    /appstores/new(.:format)               appstores#new
       edit_appstore GET    /appstores/:id/edit(.:format)          appstores#edit
            appstore GET    /appstores/:id(.:format)               appstores#show
                     PATCH  /appstores/:id(.:format)               appstores#update
                     PUT    /appstores/:id(.:format)               appstores#update
                     DELETE /appstores/:id(.:format)               appstores#destroy
appstores_rfscenario GET    /appstores/rfscenario(.:format)        appstores#rfscenario
```

Btw, here is what I saw form terminal, this is when I filled in all the fields.

```
Started POST "/appstores" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-03 22:25:54 +0800
Processing by AppstoresController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7WV4Iw/0uHNSnuXpr8qa39oFEF9gZfKm8EyHGQna0o0=", "subjectinfo"=>{"username"=>"a1", "mobile_user"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"NEXT"}
  Rendered appstores/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 88.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here is when I leave them blank, but no matter it is blank or not, it always render to index......

```
Started POST "/appstores" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-03 22:25:54 +0800
Processing by AppstoresController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7WV4Iw/0uHNSnfuXpr8qa39oFEF9gZfKm8EyHGQna0o0=", "subjectinfo"=>{"esearch"=>""}, "commit"=>"NEXT"}
  Rendered appstores/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 88.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Comment: It's not redirecting to the index, rendering the new action means it renders the view in new, the create action is under the url `/appstores` as you can see in your routes, just one is a get request and the other is a post request.

Comment: @Pavan , I use rails 4.2.4 and ruby 2.0.0, would the version cause the problem? I am trying to create another project and downgrade to rails 3.2.14 and see whether I get the same problem now.

Comment: @japed that's the wired thing happened in my create action. I did write redirect_to :index, but I always jump to index page after I click submit. I also try to add :method => "POST" in form_for, but the URL becomes http://localhost:3000/appstores?method=POST, and it still the index page.

Comment: What does the html source look like for the form element?

Comment: @Jason I made the form with twitter-bootstrap 3. Forgive my poor English, is that what you ask?

Comment: I meant when you go to the page in your browser and do "view source," what does the line with your `<form>` tag look like. I thought there might be a clue in there. Don't worry about it, though, it looks like your question got a good answer. On a side note, I noticed that you added a `<form>` tag after your `form_for` call so you could tag it with the `form-horizontal` class. The browser might exclude this second `<form>` tag. You can actually add your class to the first `<form>` tag in the `form_for` call with this hash: `html: { class: "form-horizontal" }` and get rid of the other `<form>`

Comment: It looks like `<form id="new_subjectinfo" class="new_subjectinfo" method="post" action="/appstores" accept-charset="UTF-8">`. I never realize that I can use "view source" in that way, now I can easily know what id and class it use, it always bothers me. And thanks for your suggestion for `form-horizontal`, it's useful!

Comment: Careful, though, because that is the data that comes in to the browser and not necessarily what is rendered. For instance, two `<form>` tags could appear in the source, one inside the other, but when you use "inspect element" on the form, you may see that only one of the `<form>` tags actually rendered. So it can be very instructive to examine the differences between your raw code, the "view source" data and the "inspect element" data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :via => :all` from your `routes.rb` file and never use it anymore. This pattern matches any route and it is on the first position, other routes in your file don't have a chance at all because of that.

Comment: It does help! Thanks!!!
not knowing how my previous projects survive with this line existed.